# Efficient way of hiding multiple objects from C# form

Tags: c#, forms, simplify

is there a way to hide multiple objects from one form in a more efficient way than hiding them individually.
I have a form I want to have 4 functions on; add, edit, delete and view data in a database.
When I click one i want the objects for each function to become visible and the ones not needed will be hidden.

Comment: You can use panels, or create collections of controls by yourself

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]), and [What type of questions should I avoid asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the controls in Panels. Turn the Panels on and off.
IIRC a group box does the same.
You can be more snazzy and use UserControls or CustomControls
but start with Panels to get the hang of it.

Answer (score 3):

Create collections for the controls you want to show/hide and add the respective controls to them. Then loop over these collections.

```
var controlsToHide = new List<Control>();
controlsToHide.Add(myButton);
controlsToHide.Add(otherButton);
HideAll(controlsToHide);

public void HideAll(List<Control> controls) {
    foreach(var ctrl in controls) {
        ctrl.Visisble = false;
    }
}
```